# server socket multithreading confuses with the devices

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets

I'm writing an Android app using sockets for communication. In a class called `sever` I accept clients (android devices) and open sockets for them.

Server side:

```
public void run() {
    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {

        try {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

            Client clientThread = new Client(socket);
            System.out.println("New client: " + clientThread.getName());
            new Thread(clientThread).start();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After a succesful connection the user may create a `group`, which is like a room for number of clients to connect and play together.

The group creation is done here:

Server side:

Client:

```
private void client_create() {
    this.mGroup = new Group();
    mGroup.joinPlayer(this);
    System.out.println("New group for: " + name);
}
```

Group:

```
public Group(int nClients){
    // Clients in this group
    this.clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
}

public void joinPlayer(Client player){
    clients.add(player);
}
```

Client Side:

Connection handling:

```
try {
            socket = new Socket(hostName, portNumber);

            out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    socket.getInputStream()));

            Listener listener = new Listener();
            new Thread(listener).start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I ran this programm on 2 android devices and on my localhost as the server. After the connection was made, I tried creating 2 independent different groups. While debugging it all seems legit until I reached to a point where I lost it due to the 2 different running threads.

The odd thing that happened is that after the first group was created with the first client (`clients` contains the first device client object), and then the second group with the second player (`clients` contains the second device client object), the first group `clients` array contains the second client object (from the second device).
Have you got any thoughts on that? Did I do something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. 
`Clients` was mistakly defined as static, so I guess when accessing to the `clients` array of the static object it received the last one who was created.